# Inheritance in T4 templates

Tags: c#, inheritance, t4

I'm trying to create a base class for all my .tt files so that I don't have to duplicate my code, but I can't figure out how to get it to work properly.

As far as I know, inheritance in .tt files must be done from precompiled code, so I have created another project so it gets compiled before my tt project does. I have tried so many things with no result.

This is my base class `BaseClass.cs`:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void SaveFiles(string[] filePaths)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

And this might be one of the classes I want to inherit from `BaseClass`:

```
<#@ include file="IdentificableDomainEntityTemplate.tt" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ template language="C#" inherits="BaseClass" #>

<#+
public class IdentificableDomainEntitiesGenerator : BaseClass
{
   public string AssemblyFile {get; set;}
   public string AgentNamespace {get; set;}
   public string Namespace {get; set;}
   public string EntityName {get; set;}
   public List<string> EntitiesToGenerate;
   public List<string> ReferencesToGenerate;
   public Dictionary<string, List<string>> EntityExceptionsProperties;
   public string OutputFolder{get;set;}
   public string AddToProject{get;set;}  

   public void RunCore()
   {
    this.SaveFiles(null);       
   }
}#>
```

Like I said, I've created another project so it gets compiled but I don't really know what else to try in order to inherit from `BaseClass` in my .tt files.

Comment: Is this for a Runtime T4, or a Design-time T4?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a reference to the assembly containing the `BaseClass` class in the T4 template as follows:

```
<#@ assembly name="AssemblyName.dll" #>
```

where "AssemblyName.dll" is the name of the assembly containing the `BaseClass` class. You will need to either provide the full path to the DLL, or you can use Visual Studio macros such as `$(ProjectDir)`.